# Oracle combine 2 rows into one with different join criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Records without customerId always have DT01-DT09 and WT01 and records with customerId have WIF... 
`CustomerId` is essentially missing from records with `DT` but it's that same customer.
How could I select records to get them in one row?

[image]

[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCSjQ.png)

Script I am tweaking ATM is below:

```
 select * from (
                        select
                           tqs.transactiondetailid as transactiondetailid,
                          q.productid as productid,
                          tqs.answer as QAnswer,
                          QCODE,
                          tqs.transactionversion as transactionversion,
                          tqs.CUSTOMERID AS CUSTOMERID
                        from TRANSACTIONDETAILQSHIS tqs
                        inner join question q on q.questionid = tqs.questionid 
                        and (
                              q.qcode like 'DT%'
                              or  q.qcode like 'WT%'
                              or (q.qcode like 'WIF%' and q.isthunderheadonly = 0))
        ) pivot (
        min(QAnswer) for QCODE in (
        'DT01', 'DT02', 'DT03', 'DT04', 'DT05', 'DT06', 'DT07', 'DT09', 'WT01', 'WIF3.1', 'WIF4.1', 'WIF4.2', 'WIF6.1', 'WIF7.1', 'WIF7.2', 'WIF7.3', 'WIF7.7', 'WIF7.10', 'WIF9.1', 'WIF9.6', 'WIF10.1', 'WIF10.2', 'WIF12.1', 'WIF13.1', 'WIF13.1.1', 'WIF14.1'
               ))
               where transactiondetailid =  5845
```

That `transactiondetailid =  5845`  at the end is for clarity only, normally it's all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.
Problem in all answers above is that if you eliminate CustomerId before filtering on it - you will get other customer's data **(transactionversion 9 and 10 has two customers)**, the trick is to filter the records on customerid without selecing customerid from inner select - that way the rows will collapse into one while skipping the records from second customer.

The way I did it I created a subselect (view) above that contained customerid's that I needed and then joined on that view to filter to customers that match, and if i need that customerid I can always get it from `customerv`

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT tqs.transactiondetailid AS transactiondetailid,
           q.productid AS productid,
           tqs.answer AS QAnswer,
           QCODE,
           tqs.transactionversion AS transactionversion
   FROM TRANSACTIONDETAILQSHIS tqs
   INNER JOIN question q ON q.questionid = tqs.questionid
   INNER JOIN customerv curr ON curr.transactiondetailid = tqs.transactiondetailid
   WHERE curr.CUSTOMERID = tqs.CUSTOMERID
     OR tqs.customerid IS NULL ) pivot ( min(QAnswer)
                                        FOR QCODE IN ( 'DT01', 'DT02', 'DT03', 'DT04', 'DT05', 'DT06', 'DT07', 'DT09', 'WT01', 'WIF3.1', 'WIF4.1', 'WIF4.2', 'WIF6.1', 'WIF7.1', 'WIF7.2', 'WIF7.3', 'WIF7.7', 'WIF7.10', 'WIF9.1', 'WIF9.6', 'WIF10.1', 'WIF10.2', 'WIF12.1', 'WIF13.1', 'WIF13.1.1', 'WIF14.1' )) x
WHERE x.transactiondetailid = 5845
```

see result below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GROUP BY` and get the maximum value among the Qcode value based on customer id, transaction detail id, product id, transaction version in your Sub query before the `PIVOT`

```
              select
                      tqs.transactiondetailid as transactiondetailid,
                      q.productid as productid,
                      max(tqs.answer) as QAnswer,
                      tqs.transactionversion as transactionversion,
                      max(tqs.CUSTOMERID) AS CUSTOMERID
                      max(qcode) as QCODE
                    from TRANSACTIONDETAILQSHIS tqs
                    inner join question q on q.questionid = tqs.questionid 
                    and (
                          q.qcode like 'DT%'
                          or  q.qcode like 'WT%'
                          or (q.qcode like 'WIF%' and q.isthunderheadonly = 0))
                    group by tqs.transactiondetailid, q.productid, q.productid
```

Comment: If you `group by tqs.transactiondetailid, tqs.transactionversion, q.productid` without customerid you will not gonna be able to filter other customers, have a look at transaction versions 9 or 10

Answer (score 0):

You may use GROUP BY like this:

```
select tqs.transactiondetailid as transactiondetailid,
       q.productid as productid,
       MAX(tqs.answer) as QAnswer, -- not sure about that
       MAX(QCODE) as QCODE,
       tqs.transactionversion as transactionversion,
       MAX(tqs.CUSTOMERID) AS CUSTOMERID
  from TRANSACTIONDETAILQSHIS tqs
 inner join question q
    on q.questionid = tqs.questionid 
   and (q.qcode like 'DT%'
        or  q.qcode like 'WT%'  
        or (q.qcode like 'WIF%' and q.isthunderheadonly = 0))
 GROUP BY tqs.transactiondetailid, q.productid, tqs.transactionversion
```